# Deploying SSR Nuxt.js on AWS Lambda with Cloudflare?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, cloudflare, serverless-framework

I am trying to implement a vue.js server(-less) side rendered webshop-a-like-site via nuxt.js on AWS Lambda backed with Cloudflare.

I prefer Cloudflare over Cloudfront because of http/3, image optimization features, safety against attacks, brotli and some more features that Cloudflare provides out-of-the-box.

Unfortunately i couldn't find any ressources if anyone did this before and what to take care of to work properly.

Right now my setup is like:

```
User -> Route53 -> AWS API Gateway -> AWS Lambda
 -> S3 (for static files)
 -> another AWS Lambda for dynamic data from Elasticsearch indexes
```

I am not sure where to properly integrate Cloudflare.

`I found a blogposts and threads about:

1. using Cloudflare Workers instead of AWS API Gateway 
   https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16747420
2. Creating a CNAME for Lambda provided by Cloudfront, but I am not sure if this triggers another Roundtrip to Cloudfront and additional cost? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261297
3. Connecting a Subdomain to API-Gateway
   https://medium.com/@bobthomas295/combining-aws-serverless-with-cloudflare-sub-domains-338a1b7b2bd
4. Another solution could be that I build the nuxt.js directly in a Cloudflare Worker, but I am not sure of any downsides of this solution, since CPU time is very limited in Pro Plan?
   `

Furthermore I've read an article about the need of securing the API-Gateway against attackers by only allowing Cloudflare IPs.

Did anyone of you already setup Vue + Nuxt with Cloudflare ? Am open to any other suggestions or ideas.

Thanks a lot!
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure where to properly integrate Cloudflare.

Assuming this is the crux of the question here, this is what it might look like using the notation you provided.

```
User -> Route53 -> Cloudflare -> AWS API Gateway -> AWS Lambda -> S3 -> Another lambda
```

The basic idea is that you'll want Cloudflare to be the first thing your DNS (Route53) resolves to so it can properly serve cached content *before* it ever reaches your application. Which, in this case, would start at API Gateway.

Comment: In this solution i would add a hop more:

route53 <> cloudflare.

I hoped that i can stay at count of hops of evem reduce it.

So want to achieve:

` User -> Cloudflare -> AWS API Gateway -> Lambda ... `

**or**

` User -> Cloudflare -> Cloudflare Worker -> Lambda ... `

but not sure whats best way so far, so I hoped maybe that someone got experience :)

Comment: There isn't really a way around adding the extra hop. A DNS lookup will be required no matter what solution you go with, even if you don't use route53 for DNS. The advantage to adding Cloudflare would be, in the event a user requests a cached page, your flow becomes:
`User -> Route53 -> Cloudflare`
So you take the hit of an extra hop in exchange for better performance on frequently visited resources.

If you're already building in/familiar with API Gateway and Lambda, adding Cloudflare Workers would _probably_ be unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Hi Erik,

Thanks again for your feedback.
I don't really get the advantage of using Route53 instead of Cloudflare to handle DNS? 

`User -> Route53 -> Cloudflare -> API Gateway`
compared to:
`User -> Cloudflare -> API Gateway`

looks better for me, but I feel that i am missing smth :)

Comment: Letting Cloudflare handle your DNS is totally fine, too! My only point was that DNS lookup will always happen regardless. If you go the cloudflare route, your effective flow ends up being: `User -> Cloudflare DNS -> Cloudflare CDN -> API Gateway`. The number of hops stays the same between providers, the only thing that changes is where those hops are made. Either way your Cloudflare CDN should sit just between your DNS provider and your actual application.